# How to restore contents of the scrollback buffer of Linux terminals like MacOs does it across reboots/crashes?

Tags: bash, terminal

MacOs has a very useful feature of persisting content of the scrollback buffer after reboot/crash. Can this be recreated in Linux?

`tmux-resurrect` and `tmux-continuum` don't do it. (EDIT: they do, see the answer below) KDE's save session feature doesn't do it. No terminal emulator that I've seen does it.

Is there at least a script/cron job that dumps output of the scrollback into files in `/tmp directory`? It sounds like a basic problem that must has been thought out before (all computers crash eventually and losing work is no fun, after all).

Comment: This is mostly Apple's bash startup files in /etc, I'd just copy them across and test.

Comment: I may check it then, but a little concerned that it will work only on MacOs and not on linux.

Comment: Don't take me as saying it only works on the Mac, I have no idea.  When I was still using bash, I disabled session restore with extreme prejudice.  Apple doesn't do it for any of the other shells they ship, and since bash is no longer the new user shell, the code will probably just decay.

Answer (score 2):

What I was looking for can be accomplished by adding this line to .tmux.conf in combination with the tmux plugin `tmux-resurrect`:

```
set -g @resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on'
```

[tmux-continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum) will save the session periodically (I've set it for every 5 minutes).

Also worth noting that some form of snapshots came in handy for me on couple of occasions when tmux-continuum overwrote pane-contents file before I've had a chance to inspect it. For that zfs with autozsys may save them in ~/.zfs/snapshot/autozsys_**{snap_id}**/.tmux/resurrect/pane-contents.tar.gz

For easier readability (preserving colours in bash) contents of this archive can be read with:

`zless -SR pane_contents.tar.gz`

and searched with (change **{search_query}**):

`tar xzf .tmux/resurrect/pane_contents.tar.gz --to-command 'grep --label="$TAR_FILENAME" -H **{search_query}** ; true'`

Comment: This is a great answer for KDE users - can you say anything about GNOME users - or users of any of the popular *after-market* terminal apps (e.g. Terminator, Guake, etc)?? Or, is it just a matter of installing the tmux plugin for any terminal app?

Comment: Just installing this tmux plugin. It should work independent of any desktop environment. Any terminal emulator will be able to access it by attaching to that tmux session. It has worked for me really well since then - saved my "sessions" across a few accidental reboots.

Comment: Thanks for that! The [URL for tmux-plugins](https://github.com/tmux-plugins) has the `resurrect` plugin, and another one that looks good also - `contiuum`.  You should add this info to your answer - I think you'd get more upvotes. I've not had time to try them yet, but will give you some feedback here if you're interested?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I've expanded on the answer. Tmux-continuum came in very handy for me, as well.

Comment: Are you able to restore your entire scrollback buffer with the resurrect and/or continuum plugins?

Comment: yes, all of tmux scrollbacks of all opened panes/windows/sessions should be saved in .tmux/resurrect/pane_contents.tar.gz file

Comment: ... but **not** displayed in the restored terminal window? Do you find that less useful than a scrollback buffer that's in the terminal window itself?

Comment: sorry for the late reply and for the confusion in my last message. I meant that **both** the restored terminal window and pane_contents.tar.gz should show the entire content of the previously saved tmux sessions' scrollbacks. The previous sessions should be available for example by pressing *prefix+s*. The reason why I mentioned pane_contents.tar.gz is only as a fallback in case anything went wrong with restoring scrollbacks in the running tmux daemon (which happened to me a few times, but YMMV).

Comment: Yes - the added configuration line in your answer works with the `resurrect` plug-in; i.e. the scrollback is also restored :)  I've not tried `continuum` yet, but I'm confident it works there also. This is a great Q&A IMO - especially given that it seems ***only*** macOS terminal emulators (`Terminal.app` & `iTerm2`) seem to restore the scrollback. I'm astounded really - astounded that there is no Linux terminal emulator offering this feature... I wonder why?

Comment: I also wish distros Linux provided tmux and some of its plugins out of the box (or at least as an opt-in). One other thing that may be worth noting, although I'm not a Mac user, but from what I gathered restoring session scrollbacks across reboots in terminal/iterm only works for bash, while tmux resurrect should work across all shells.

Comment: Mmmm - No, session scrollback restoration isn't limited to `bash` in macOS. Specifically, `iTerm2` & `Terminal.app` restore `bash` & `zsh` at least. I've not tried any other shells, but AFAIK the scrollback is independent of which shell you're using. The command history is another matter...

Comment: Thanks, good to know